# how to get the wp_woocommerce_session_ values in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, session-cookies

I am trying to set a custom cookie value in browser.
When I try to use  `$_Cookie` it get destroyed once I close my browser and my thoughts are woocommerce destroying any cookie before setting its own cookie.

So I have decided to use woocommerce cookie in order to save a custom field in database using Cookie as my **Primary Key** when user is **NOT** logged in and when user registers I get the value that I saved in database again using cookie value as `key` and save it into users table.

Now Im trying to access the woocommerce cookie (wp_woocommerce_session_) which I dont know how can I access it???

I wanted to try `WC_Session_Handler::get_session( $customer_id);` from [this](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_session_handlerget_session/) [link](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_session_handlerget_session/) but the customer_id is always 0 and the way Im trying to get it is :

```
function get_customerorderid(){
    global $post;
    $order_id = $post->ID;

    // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    // Get the user ID from WC_Order methods
    $user_id = $order->get_user_id(); // or $order->get_customer_id();

    return $user_id;
}
```

I think if user doesnt have any order , we cant get customer ID but Im not sure about it

So How Can I access woocommerce cookie ( if there is any without user putting an order) Or how can I create a cookie using `setCookie` from php and avoid the destruction of it? ( I do set time to one year)

Comment: WC()->session->get_session_cookie()

Comment: i tried 'WC()->session->get_session_cookie()' to get the customer cookie but this code return  zero

Comment: What is the value of $_COOKIE?

Comment: the same value is remain when i initialize the cookie

Comment: $_COOKIE is an array. Does $_COOKIE have an item whose key starts with "wp_woocommerce_session_"? E.g. $_COOKIE['wp_woocommerce_session_86a9106ae65537651a8e456835b316ab'] => 1||1581058324||1581054724||0e7f633b43dc5e081103ee545555257d

Comment: I noticed your question has been significantly edited. Now I don't understand the question. There are no WooCommerce cookies when a user is not logged in. Cookies are destroyed when you close browser only if your browser has been configured to do so otherwise cookies will persists until they expire.

Comment: WooCommerce cookies are set to expire after 48 hours. I think the default configuration of browsers is NOT to clear cookies when the browser is closed. For security reasons I have manually configured my browsers to clear cookies when the browser is closed but I don't think this is true of most users.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this javascript code

```
function getCookie(key)
{
    var i,x,y,z,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");

    for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
    {
        x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
        x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
        z=x.substr(0,key.length)
        if (z==key)
        {
            return unescape(y);
        }
     }
}

getCookie('wp_woocomerce_session_')
```